# how to batch convert file names to lowercase and also update their references in the corresponding files

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing, lowercase, batch-rename, dreamweaver

Adobe Dreamweaver does this beautifully but only with single file name. In dreamweaver, as i select a file name in the right side 'local files' box, F2 and rename the file a dialog opens to confirm to update the relevant reference in any of the html, css file in the current site as well.

I am looking to batch this process as I have thousands of files with camel case format and I need to change all of them into lowercase. Problem here is that I will also have to update their relevant references too in any of the html, css etc. files which is a tedious task.

So just looking for a tool or way to batch this process where I can convert all file names to lowercase and also update their corresponding references / entries. The reference names will probably be inside a html or css file present in the given folder or any directory.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of refining I have created this batch script that will loop through all the specified files in the current directory and rename them to lowercase, and also go through each file's contents and change any uppercase letters to lowercase.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=0
for %%a in (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z) do (
set upper[!num!]=%%a
set /a num+=1
)
set num=0
for %%b in (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z) do (
set lower[!num!]=%%b
set /a num+=1
)
for %%x in (C:\Users\folder1,C:\anotherfolder) do (
cd /d %%x
(
for %%c in (*.*) do (
set file=%%c
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%e in (%%c) do (
set line=%%e
for /l %%d in (0,1,25) do (
set u=!upper[%%d]!
set l=!lower[%%d]!
call :RETURN !u! !l!
)
echo !line! >>new.txt
)
del %%c /f /q
ren new.txt %%c
ren %%c !file!
)
)
)

:RETURN
set file=!file:%1=%2!
set line=!line:%1=%2!
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for putting your time and efforts, really appreciate it but I am looking for something more precise, may be a tool where I can select directories and it automatically modifies everything. Problem with this script might be that if there is a word with a specific filename it will also change whereas I would need to change only the words which are src and href references. Hope you get my requirement but really thanks for giving me some alternate solution if I don't get something very specific to my requirement.

Comment: Ok, not to worry. I will see if I can make it a bit more specific, and will post anything I can add :)

Comment: I have added in the functionality of being able to choose the folders you rename the files in. Just add your folders in the body of the middle `for` loop, where I have put `C:\Users\folder1` and `C:\anotherfolder` (these must be full paths), and you can specify files as well, using wildcards, in the `for` loop below that, where I have used every file (`*.*`).

Comment: Apart from that I don't think I can do much else with it, batch is just to limited to start checking for tags in the files. It would probably be possible, but it's not something I'm going to try and do :)